# Cooking measures conversions app (eg. 40g of granulated sugar → 47 mL) for Android, open source

Tags: android, open-source, cooking

I don't have a scale, so I cook using such a tool to measure volume (millilitres):

[image: measuring cup]

When a recipe tells me to add 40g of granulated sugar, I check websites like [this one](http://www.onlineconversion.com/weight_volume_cooking.htm) to perform the conversion.

Is there an Android app for this?

Requirements:

- Measures for most common ingredients
- Weight and volume in various units, at least: mL, cup, g
- Open source (I will most probably want to customize it, and contribute translations)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Cooking Conversions](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.makeproducts.conversions)

**Description**
Cooking Conversions helps you:
1. Convert units of measure by volume and by weight.
2. Scale a recipe from X servings to Y servings.v
3. Convert between Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures.
4. Substitute an ingredient you may have run out of.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.makeproducts.conversions

---

Another Option is : [Recipe Convert Free](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redbinary.rmc)

**Description**
Recipe unit conversion calculator: Convert volume & weight measurements in recipes. Makes scaling servings yields up or down easy for cooks, bakers, & chefs at home or the restaurant
**FEATURES**:
* Values can be entered and displayed as either fractions or decimals
* Will make the coveted "grams to cups" conversion, as well as other 
weight/volume conversions, based on user-selectable weight factor parameter
* Quick switch between scaling yields to general 1:1 units (by tapping "Yield" section to collapse it)
* Also serves as a general reference of cooking units, temperatures & gas marks, and decimal equivalents to fractions

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.redbinary.rmc

Comment: Looks OK feature-wise, but they are not open source, right? (my third requirement)

Comment: @NicolasRaoul  I really don't know. It's not stated neither in google play nor in the developer sites

Comment: Yes I checked the developer sites too... if it were Open Source they would say it. So they are not Open Source.

Comment: Yes but it still solve your problem

Comment: The third requirement is an integral part of the question. I am looking for an app that satisfies all 3 requirements. Thanks for your effort though!

Answer (score 1):

The classic Unix software [units](https://www.gnu.org/software/units/), now a GNU project, does this on the command line. It's open source and the unit database is a simple text file which can be modified very easily. It comes with predefined measures for cooking from *The Cake Bible* by Rose Levy Beranbaum.

```
$ units
2411 units, 71 prefixes, 33 nonlinear units

You have: 40g
You want: cups sugar
        * 0.2
        / 5
You have: 40g
You want: mL sugar
        * 47.317647
        / 0.021133764
You have:
```

There are several ports of it for Android. I've never used any of them.

- [Android Units](http://staticfree.info/projects/units/) ([`info.staticfree.android.units`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.staticfree.android.units&hl=en))
- [Units for Android (`org.quexotic.gnuunits`)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.quexotic.gnuunits&hl=en)